# Does Vasicek interest rate model had any derivation that follows from a list of assumptions?

Tags: interest-rates, reference-request, interest

I can't find that anywhere online and It doesn't seems to me that this model originated come from intuition or some human motivation but rather it is coming from computerized curve fitting as all the textbook leave out the details...

The question is, did anybody here find one or two explanation at all?

Thank You in advance for enlighten me.

Comment: Vasicek model was developed a long time ago (1977). It was the first interest rate model. Only assumption was that interest rates are mean reverting, and this is the mathematically simplest model having that property. It is not considered very advanced by present day standards, just a first step.

Comment: @noob2 - Although Vasicek models did not had a detail oriented/rigorous explanation on how it work, do other more complicated interest rate/finance models had math derivation just as some math/stat model(gamma distribution, exponential distribution, normal distribution) had both intuitve explanation and rigorous derivation? Thank You Very Much for your kind attention and detailed oriented comment on top.

Comment: The model itself is known as Ornstein Uhlenbeck process in physics. Did you read Vasicek paper?

Comment: @Aksakal The paper seems to be esoteric and long but my question is why do analyst assuming that this model fit to estimate interest rate but not other models that may share some similar properties, for example the models with the mean reverting  propertie?

Comment: @AlanLui, you'll never get an answer to a question like that in finance. This is not a fundamental science like physics. If anything, there can be a ton of reasons why this model should not be the right model. It's simple and economists like to use it in studies where the exact evolution of rates is not so important. It captures mean reverting characteristic.

Comment: @Aksakal But in statistics, I heard a subject called testing statistical hypothesis and now it come to mind(for example, the notion of uniformly most powerful test can test out if a stat test is better than another test in precision of all the critical region of some data) although not 100 % sure what the whole subject does, but I was guessing Finance had its own version of the subject that either includes as a section or a chapter in the textbook, and so I think there is some justification of the model I asked.

Comment: @AlanLui, good luck with that.